# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis not working on V-chip

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to limit the width of a v-chip by using `text-overflow: ellipsis` but it seems that Vuetify `v-chip` doesn't recognize it.

I want to avoid this problem :
[image]

```
<v-chip-group
             v-model="selected"
             mandatory
             column
             active-class="primary--text"
        >
            <v-chip v-for="(item, i) in recipes" :key="i"
                    class="chip-overflow"
                    @click:close="deleteListedRecipe(item)"
                    close>
                {{ item.name }}
            </v-chip>
        </v-chip-group>
```

```
    .chip-overflow {
        max-width: 150px;
        padding: 2px 5px;
        display:block;

        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of adding ellipsis CSS to `v-chip__content` class

```
    .chip-overflow{
            max-width: 150px;
            padding: 2px 5px;
        }


    ::v-deep .v-chip__content {
      display: inline-block !important;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

 ::v-deep .v-chip__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  width: 24px;
}
```

Codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oNgMzxq

Comment: Any idea why the selector .v-chip__content is not recognized by my Webstorm IDE ? It says .v-chip__content is never used. Also, even though the ellipsis works on the chips, the close icon is not showing.

Comment: @Philx94, add css for v-chip_close and adjust positions to display accordingly,  added to post and codepen for reference

Comment: I needed to write it this way ```::v-deep .v-chip__content```

Comment: In the codepen in chrome there is no ellipsis, and the text in the chip is weirdly aligned to the top of the chip

Answer (score 8):

I was able to truncate text the Vuetify way doing this:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="6">
    <v-chip close>
      <span class="text-truncate">
        {{ product.title }}
      </span>
    </v-chip>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

The trick here is the `cols=6` which limits the elements width and the span with the `text-truncate` class which adds the ellipsis css. Vuetify documentation: [truncate text](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#wrapping-and-overflow)

Comment: Very clean solution +1